Sales data trend
I have my historical sales data and I want to check for the trend (increase, decrease or no change). When I do my annual line graph, the slop of my linear equation is positive (indicating increase) but when I do the monthly graph and show my linear equation, the slope is negative (veeeery small, but negative). I am not sure what this means or if a linear equation is the best way to analyze my sales data. If I don't put the linear equation is very hard to see a level in my sales data.

If you could describe a bit more what you mean by plotting "annually" vs. "monthly", that would help you get a better answer. I can guess and conjecture, but best if we know exactly what your data consists off. One possibility (but I am guessing) is that you have e.g. daily sales data. You can either plot all the daily sales numbers for the year and get one regression, or add all the sales for a month, and then plot the monthly totals, and get another regression. But is that really your situation? If this is the case ... cont

...cont, one possibility is that your daily sales figures (what you can annual) contain some "outliers". When plotted "annually", they pull the regression line one way; but when added to the rest of the monthly figures, they are "averaged out", and thus do not affect the regression as much. Maybe a plot of your 2 regressions would help?

Hello. Thank you for answering.
I have monthly sales data (jan, feb, mar,...) from 2017 to 2023. when I create a graph using the monthly data I get one linear equation where the slope is negative (so I thought sales are decreasing over time) but then I use the same data, grouped by month to create other graph and then the linear equation has a positive slope. But I think is as you mentioned, there are outliers (specially during Covid 2020) that could impact that.

So I did a compound annual growth rate to have a better understanding and smooth the trend of my sales data so these fluctuations will not impact/mask the tread of my sales data.
Do you think is a better approach to use the CAGR to check the level and trend of my time series data?

OK, so to get this straight. You have monthly sales data: if you do a regression of this data over 7 years (7*12=84 data points), you get a barely negative slope. But if you accumulate the data by year (so only 7 data points... a bit weak for a regression), you get a positive slope? So indeed, monthly Covid outliers could drag your regression down. And if you aggregated the data by quarter, you may get yet another answer. ... cont

...cont.  I would suggest you take a look at the confidence interval of the slopes you obtained; my hunch is that, whether positive or negative, these CI's all include 0 (by month, by quarter, by year), meaning you really have no trend. Statistically, sales are flat. Now, if ever you get both significant positive and negative slopes, depending on how you aggregate the data, now we would have an interesting case, worth more investigation. Otherwise, the best conclusion is "it's flat"...

Thank you for the explanation.
